# Is it possible to run breadth first instead of depth first in tox?

Tags: python, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, tox

I have a suite of small tests that take about 40 seconds in total to run, and I have a suite of medium tests that take about 40 minutes in total to run.

I would love the ordering to run like this:

1. py27 small tests
2. py37 small tests
3. py27 medium tests
4. py37 medium tests

Instead, tox runs it like

1. py27 small tests
2. py27 medium tests
3. py37 small tests
4. py37 medium tests

The problem with this is if something simple breaks a small test, I want to know about it immediately. The medium tests (like integration tests) are an extra layer of security that can smoke out more issues but take a much longer time to run through.

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,py37
[testenv:py27]
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    pytest-mock
    pylint
    ; packages specified by the setup.py cover the other dependencies for py2.7
commands =
    pytest -v --ignore-glob="*medium*" --doctest-modules
    pytest -v tests/medium_tests
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a tox expert but something like this might help:

```
[tox]
envlist = {s,m}-{py27,py37}

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
commands =
    s: pytest -v -k 'not medium'
    m: pytest -v -k 'medium'
```

All your short test commands should have prefix `s:` and all medium test commands have prefix `m:`
The important thing is the env list `{s,m}-{py27,py37}` which will run through `s-py27`, `s-py37`, `m-py27`, `m-py37` in that order.

Comment: Aha! This is the answer I was looking for. I see my mental model of how to actually use tox was a bit off. I kept trying to make it work via multiple testenv:<variation>, not realizing that isn't really the intention of that and just an anti-pattern that it can be used as a tool to do some of it. This is very clear! Thanks!!